# How to proof: Suppose $R$ and $S$ are equivalence relations on a non-empty set $A$, then $R \setminus S$ is not transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've able to proof that $R \setminus S$ is symmetric and not reflexive, but don't know how to start the proof of $R \setminus S$ is not transitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn’t quite true: if $R\subseteq S$, then $R\setminus S=\varnothing$, which is vacuously transitive. However, as long as $R\setminus S\ne\varnothing$, you can let $\langle a,b\rangle\in R\setminus S$. Then $\langle b,a\rangle\in R\setminus S$. Can you construct a counterexample to transitivity from these ordered pairs?

Comment: So $R$ and $S$ is transitive, since they're equivalence relations to $A$, so by definition of transitive: $\forall x \forall y \forall \in A(xRy \land yRz \rightarrow xRz)$, so that means $<x,y>,<y,z>,<x,z>\in R$  and is also in $S$, but in this case $R \setminus S$, $<x,y>,<y,z>,<x,z>\notin S$, so $R\setminus S$ is not transitive. That's how I tried to solve it.

Comment: @YZY: You’re ignoring my suggestion. You can use what I wrote to construct a very specific counterexample to transitivity involving the elements $a$ and $b$ of $A$.

Comment: Hmmm... Is it $<a,b> \in R \setminus S$ and $<b,a> \in R \setminus S$ but $<a,a> \notin R \setminus S$?

Comment: @YZY: Yes, exactly. You’ve already shown that $\langle a,a\rangle\notin R\setminus S$ and that $R\setminus S$ is symmetric, so the moment you have even one pair $\langle a,b\rangle\in R\setminus S$, you have a counterexample to transitivity like this.

Comment: I see, Thank you so much!

Comment: @YZY: You’re very welcome.